# Automate series of shell commands (sed and node scripts)

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, sed

For my project, there is data updated daily that I download, parse with a basic `sed` command, and then upload using a node script. I'm wondering how I can streamline the process to involve only selecting the initial files, and have a program/automation run the `sed` commands, then run the node scripts. Here's an example of what the current (very manual) process looks like:

1. Create a folder called `4-22-2021` and download `INFILE.txt` to that location
2. Navigate to that folder in terminal
3. run `sed 's/~//g' INFILE.txt | sed 's/","/~/g' | sed 's/"//g' > OUTFILE.csv`
4. run `npm run daily -- 4-22-2021` (the argument to this command just specifies the folder in which the parsed files to upload are located)

So basically, what I want to simplify this process to look like is:

1. Create a folder called `4-22-2021` and download `INFILE.txt` to that location
2. Select that folder from a Finder dropdown and have the rest of the process run automatically

What is the best approach to simplifying/automating this string of terminal commands and processes? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `mkdir` creates directories/folder, `wget` or `curl` can download things on the internet, and your `sed` invocation can be just one, `sed 's/~//g;s/","/~/g;s/"//g' infile.txt > outfile.txt`

Comment: `sed 's/~//g'` is better written as `tr -d '~'`.  Similarly, remove double quotes with `tr -d '"'`

Comment: Write all commands in a file, insert the first line `#!/bin/bash` and `chmod +x thatfile`. Try running that file with `./thatfile` testing how it works. Happy? Look at crontab.